# How can I perform a insertion sort based on the lvalue of a dictionary

Tags: python, insertion-sort

```
item_data = {1:[11,21,31,41],
             3:[13,23,33,43],
             5:[15,25,35,45],
             2:[12,22,32,42],
             4:[14,24,34,44],
             14:[14,14,14,14]}

def insertion_sort():
    #insertion sort
```

I am trying to perform a insertion sort base on the value: item_data[key][1]
but i have no idea how to do it
A complete newbie here asking for some help

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to do this comparison `key[i-1]  > key[i]`.

Then:

```
...
while firstArrayIsgreater(key[i], key[i-1]) and i > 0:
                key[i-1],key[i] = key[i],key[i-1]
                i-=1
...
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. But I don't get what you are trying to do. Sorry I am a complete newbie. I am trying to sort base on the item_data [key] [1]